# How to prevent users from moving pages?

Tags: javascript

I know somethings like this;

```
<script>
function out()  {
    alert('No, stay here.');
    //What to do?...
}
</script>

<body onUnload="out()">
<input />
</body>
```

I got some response from other community

```
<script>
function out()  {
    alert('No, stay here.');
    location.href='thisPage.html';
}
```

But this will reload the page. I want to prevent users from moving pages without reloading page. Thank you

Comment: It might just be me, but I really dislike a page that attempt to keep me there against my will and I often (always_?) just close the browser on public sites that do this. I even have a couple that I have blocked from even showing up in the first place.  That being said, on a private site with validation it's not a huge issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event and take the steps whatever you want:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  // whatever you want to do now
};
```

With this, you can redirect users to some other page if they try to move away from current page or any action you want to perform there.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever do this: there's a reason a user wants to leave the page, so don't force him/her to stay. A better option would be to use [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) to ask for confirmation before leaving the page.

Comment: Ah Because it's a contineous input process. So users can't leave page until the whole input process is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `return false;` instead of `location.href='thisPage.html';`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning nothing, add

```
return false;
```

to the end, that should work

Answer (score 0):

:)

```
function out()  {
    alert('No, stay here.');
    return false;
}
```